# Hadn't Barney already won the belt?

Tags: plot-explanation, how-i-met-your-mother

In *How I Met Your Mother*, we all remember that Barney and Ted made a bet for a belt to see who will able to do a threesome first. So when Ted's wedding day (not the actual but with Stella which was cancelled eventually).

So barney had an urge that he did not want to do intercourse as he was waiting for Robin but someone (I don't remember who!) was hitting on him. Then Robin knocks his room and seeing inside left in disgust, so everyone thought that would have been the girl hitting on him, but just 10 seconds after the same girl arrives and looks inside, we all thought the girl will also leave but she went inside (I am assuming that what Robin saw was another girl). So would not this be counted as a threesome? Then I thought the TV show makers must have forgotten the bet.

Eventually, they made an episode in which Ted again met Tory (I am not good with names, so I may be wrong) or the pineapple girl (when Ted had forgotten what happened last night), so eventually, in that episode, Ted was close to having threesome and Barney was scared to hell that he will lose the bet. Was this some mistake by TV show makers?

Comment: This is a completely incomprehensible stream-of-consciousness & wall-of-text. See if you can pull come coherent detail out of it & then re-cast your question.

Comment: Fantastic job, AJ. I wish I could +1 individual edits.

Comment: @AJ Is it not "Ted" rather than "Tedd"? I've never watched it, but would presume so.

Comment: @Darren Me neither. I capitalized the name OP has mentioned.

Comment: @AJ, According to IMDB, it is.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few misconceptions and assumptions in the question.

1. It's unproven that there was a second girl in the bedroom during Ted and Stella's wedding. I don't remember this implication, having watched the show multiple times.
2. Even if there was a third girl, the Bro Code stipulates limitations to "the tricycle". If any of these rules were violated, it would not count as a victory for the belt. As per [Article 80](https://books.google.be/books?id=K3OlS-99_rEC&lpg=PA80&ots=ZWqYvyM0DB&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]

3. Even if Barney had won the belt during Ted and Stella's wedding, it's not about *winning* the belt, it's about **holding** the belt. Whoever holds the belt is considered the reigning champion (like the belt in wrestling, or the yellow shirt in cycling) When Ted allegedly rode the tricycle, he would be taking the belt from Barney, and Barney didn't want the belt to pass on to Ted as he would have to give up his position as reigning champion.

Those are a lot of unproven ifs for your interpretation to be the valid one.

---

As an aside, Barney's reluctance to let Ted win the belt is in clear violation of Article 80. Barney did admit to his reluctance conflicting with the code during the episode, but there is a clear argument to be made for Barney's title being revoked on grounds of unsportsmanlike conduct. It's even stipulated in [the Bro Code](https://the-bro-codes.tumblr.com/violations) itself:

> **There is no greater affront to the spirit of The Bro Code than a willing violation.** [..] any premeditated infraction of The Bro Code is inexcusable. When a Bro violates The Bro Code, he hurts not only his Bros but also himself, because he is no longer Bro worthy.
>
> [..]
>
> If and when a violation occurs, a Bro has the right to administer the offending Bro a level of punishment befitting the infraction. He may choose from the Approved Punishments list.
>
> **Approved Punishments**
>
> - Revocation of wingman status
> - Text blackout
> - Designated all-time tip leaver
> - Assigned to solar-refraction seat in living room
> - Removal from inappropriate email forwards list
> - Waterboarding
> - Temporary blacklist from barbecues/football Sundays
> - Loss of permanent shotgun status
> - Bumped from top position on "not using season tickets" list
> - Removal from holiday card mailing list
> - Revocation of airport picking/drop-off privileges
> - Must help offended Bro move heavy furniture
> - Temporary removal from usual golf foursome
> - Must return stuff loaned from offended Bro…even stuff he thinks his Bro forgot about
> - No longer allowed to borrow the truck
> - Offended Bro no longer required to bring beer over

Comment: See then why was barney telling a story about he failed to have a threesome in the same episode when tedd met tory (which he told he spilled something on a mat , but after wards he told that he was nervous thus making a impression he had never done it).If there was not another girl in the room why was barney without his shirt , why did robin left in disgust and what was the girl who was hitting on barney checking on peeping inside the room and then smiled?And barney already has broken the bro code once !!

Comment: When Stella's sister arrives at Barney room, she says "Is that the girl from the front desk?" before walking in. So a threesome is strongly implied.

Answer (score 1):

The episode with Stella's and Ted's (cancelled) wedding ([Shelter Island, Season 4, Episode 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelter_Island_(How_I_Met_Your_Mother))) where Barney (probably) has a threesome is after the episode about the belt ([Third Wheel, Season 3, Episode 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Wheel)) where Barney tells the story about his failed attempt at a threesome. So there are no mistakes in the timeline of the show.

Comment: Sorry that was a blunder from my side